# Deploying Pylons with uWSGI

Tags: python, apache, deployment, pylons, uwsgi

We're trying to move our intranet to Pylons. My boss is trying to set up Pylons to use uWSGI behind Apache so he can set up multiple, independent applications. However, he's having a difficult time getting it set up, with some apparent code problems in the C source code for uWSGI. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to deploy Pylons applications that might help us out?

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: It's worth noting that you can not just run uwsgi and then connect to it, like you would with paste. It has to be connected to via a webserver.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I did it:

http://tonylandis.com/python/deployment-howt-pylons-nginx-and-uwsgi/

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use paste for deploying pylons on uWSGI:

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/UsePaste

Answer (score 0):

The Pylons documentation contains [very detailed instructions about deployment](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/deployment.html).

Is there anything *specific* that isn't working properly?

Comment: In the link nothing is said about uwsgi.