# Cherokee + uWSGI + Pylons

Tags: python, pylons, cherokee, uwsgi

I have successfully deployed a Django app with uWSGI + Cherokee.
However, I want to experiment with Pylons before I go decide on Django.

So far I have followed the instructions/recommendations here:
[Deploying Pylons with uWSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217679/deploying-pylons-with-uwsgi)

Paster serve works without a hitch. But when I try to serve via uWSGI, I get nowhere:

`/usr/bin/uwsgi -s :5000 --paste config:/var/www/env/helloworld/development.ini -H /var/www/env -M`

My uWSGI master and worker processes are spawned. SO, I visit http://localhost:5000
This is what I get:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.
```

And my terminal reads back (and repeats when I refresh browser):

```
invalid request block size: 21573...skip
```

What am I doing wrong?
I cannot find any guide or step-by-step specific for uWSGI + Cherokee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not visit http://localhost:5000. 5000 it's the port use for the communication between Cherokee and uWSGI. So you're trying to access uWSGI directly. You need to configure Cherokee and then go to the address:port you have configured in Cherokee to see your website.

Docs:

- [Cherokee-uWSGI](http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_uwsgi.html)
- [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc095)